# jupyter notebook "c.NotebookApp.certfile = " error

Tags: jupyter, config

I'm trying to open jupyter notebook server on windows 10.
but error was occurred as below picture. I don't understand that ..

jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '192.168.219.177'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
c.NotebookApp.password = u'argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=10240,t=10,p=8$wBD+Gu+NqxXuNCD+hf3Jqw$AKcHN5Zuq+TYjYhWUI+9/A'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'd:\study\jupyter'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'c:\users\doo\ssl\mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'C:\Users\doo\ssl\mykey.key'
```

error code

```
[E 22:39:05.760 NotebookApp] Exception while loading config file C:\Users\doo\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
        config = loader.load_config()                                                                                         File "C:\Users\doo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 616, in load_config                      self._read_file_as_dict()                                                                                             File "C:\Users\doo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 648, in _read_file_as_dict               exec(compile(f.read(), conf_filename, 'exec'), namespace, namespace)                                                  File "C:\Users\doo\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py", line 1259                                                        c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'c:\users\doo\ssl\mycert.pem'
```

Comment: Could you please include the full backtrace? Also, it would be helpful if you included the error and code inline in the question itself rather than images. Have you checked that that certfile actually exists on your disk?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the error message correctly.

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape

I solved this issue.